# Cordova - WebGL works fine on phone but not on emulator [Without CrossWalk]

Tags: android, cordova, webgl, cesiumjs, crosswalk

I am trying to build an application with `CesiumJs.org`, The files work fine on both `chrome`, `android phone with v8` and `android phone with v9` all works fine. When I try the same APK on `Bluestack`, `genymotion` and `Android VD` it throws me an error as below.

I tried using `crosswalk` that worked fine but as my client is from China not everyone has access to `Google Play`. What could be the best option to fix this up

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the actual problem? Only thing I know is that in native Android phone the crosswalk project is not needed anymore as the Cordova uses chrome behind the scenes. But for emulators you probably need crosswalk if they have not updated the webview to use native Chrome yet. So my advice is to develop with a real phone and skip the emulators.

Comment: My problem is I have to run the APK on the Andriod phone. I am not able to run the CesiumJS on emulators. Also, I understand the crosswalk project is not needed anymore. But, How to run fix above error on emulators? other than crosswalk.

Comment: For me it looks like the emulators probably need to be updated to have support for latest chrome with webview. I guess that is up to the platform provider, so for you its better to just get a real phone and skip the emulator or then find emulator which has newest chrome support